# Uploading Documents for Members/Contacts

Tags: civimember

What is the easiest way to allow contacts (in our case, faculty) to upload information related to published articles or publications they've written to be viewed by a generic audience?

Comment: What CMS (Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Documents extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/documents